# Can't login after update Raspberry Arch Linux

Tags: login, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

Today, I tried to update my Arch Linux on Raspberry, but I got an error:

```
error: could not prepare transaction
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
package: /bin exists in filesystem
package: /sbin exists in filesystem
package: /usr/bin exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

So, I followed the instructions provided [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Q:_I_get_an_error_when_updating:_.22file_exists_in_filesystem.22.21).

After update some packages with `pacman -S --force` (including the package shadow), I can't login with any account and getting the message `Access denied`.

Did I something wrong? The passwords accounts were reseted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ended up with a pretty borked up installation, after upgrading last time (just because I didn't read the instruction beforehand)!
What I did, is login with a archlinux CD (a bootable USB stick would do it as well) and the chrooted in to my 'original' linux and updated everything from there.
I gotta run right now, but if you would like to have further info I am glad to give some more...

Comment: It is the only solution I see for now. The problem is that now I do not have physical access to the Raspberry, only over SSH.

Answer (score 2):

You might have overwritten `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` when you did `pacman -S --force shadow`. Trying to log in on a virtual console (i.e., tty for keyboard and HDMI monitor) or the serial port (UART connected to some of the GPIO pins) will be no more successful.

Remove the SD card from the Raspberry Pi, insert it into another computer running Linux and with shadow (so likely any relatively modern distro), and either:

- Edit `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` on the SD card manually.
- Fix the `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/passwd` using the shadow suite:

  1. If the user isn't in `/etc/shadow` or `/etc/passwd`, recreate the user.

     ```
     sudo useradd -M -R /path/to/sd/card/mount/point whatever_your_rpi_username_is
     ```
  2. Reset your user's password.

     ```
     sudo passwd -R /path/to/sd/card/mount/point whatever_your_rpi_username_is
     ```

Sync and unmount the SD card, then put it back in the Pi and try booting from it.

Other users on the Raspberry Pi might have been fudged or completely missing too.

Logging in over SSH should change nothing versus logging on the console if you overwrote `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`.

Follow [important Arch Linux news](https://archlinux.org). The [most recent](https://www.archlinux.org/news/binaries-move-to-usrbin-requiring-update-intervention/) would have saved you the grief. All binaries in `/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/sbin` got moved to `/usr/bin` and you still have something thereunder, hence why pacman is complaining. Follow the instructions in that article but use  your judgement. If they don't fix the problem entirely (you are in an unclean state after all), you *may* be able to get away with manually moving everything in `/bin`, `/sbin`, and `/usr/sbin` into `/usr/bin` and trying again.

Do not use `--force` unless you know what you are doing or explicitly told to do so by Arch devs.